# How to Validate the JSON element is empty or not?

Tags: java, json

Iam getting a response as

```
{
    "isSuccess": true,

     "message": "No Intent found",
  
     "result": {

           "isSuccess": false,

            "message": "Happy to Help You",

            "endOfConv": true,

            "text": "Sorry I don't understand. Please rephrase your statement.",

            "additionalInfo": {},

            "conversationFlag": "QWE"
}
```

In the above additionalInfo is "{}", I want to validate which is empty or not. I tried this below

```
{
        JsonPath jsonpath = responseResult.jsonPath();
        if(jsonpath.get("result.additionalInfo").toString()!="{}")
        {
           System.out.println(jsonpath.get("result.additionalInfo").toString());
        }
}
```

Kindly help me on this